# World subregions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to plot data on a world map whose countries may or may not be split up by subregion. I'll use a toy example to illustrate what I mean. All countries have a value of 0, except for Canada (a region) and New York (a subregion in region USA), which will have a value of 1. The rest of region USA will be 0.

I load in the world data map and create a vector of all the regions and subregions.

```
world <- map_data("world")
country <- c(unique(world$region), unique(world$subregion))
```

Then I'll make my data: Everywhere will have a value of 0 except for Canada and New York. Then I'll combine the country vector and stats vector into the dataframe for ggplot.

```
stats = numeric(length(country)) # set all data to 0
set1 <- c("Canada", "New York")
stats[is.element(country, set1)] <- 1
mydf = data.frame(country = country, stats = stats)
```

When I plot this, Canada is 1 but all of the USA (including New York) is 0.

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(map_id = country)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = stats), map = world) +
    expand_limits(x = world$long, y = world$lat)
```

Removing region USA from my data frame just eliminates it from the map. Making the stats element NA for the USA region greys it out. I've played around with only including subregions from the world map but can't seem to figure out how to include the regions that have no subregions.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you should consider using shapefiles with proper administrative districts. doing this with the built-in maps is going to be a bit of a hack. while you have provided a good base question, it'd be useful to know what you're ultimately fully trying to do as we may be able to suggest optimized shapefiles for your task.